# Why it doesn´t work?

Tags: php, wordpress

I´m writing that to give permission automatically an user to post when user have finished the purchase in woocommerce, **but not before to buy**, 
but I don´t know how to do it, Wordpress is something new for me and php too. The following code doesn´t fail, but it doesn´t work. Can you help me, please?? By the way,
I´m writing this code on functions.php, I guess that´s the proper file.

Thank you very much in advance.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'so_payment_complete' );
   function so_payment_complete( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $user = $order->get_user();
    if( isset($user) ){ 
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
    $user->add_cap( 'publish_posts' ); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$user_id is not defined.
WC_Order::get_user() returns a WP_User so a new WP_User is not necessary.